# curl PowerShell works, batch file doesn't

Tags: batch-file, curl

I do have a PowerShell script which is working fine - it downloads a Google-Spreadsheet and saves it as target.csv:

```
curl https://some-url.com -O target.csv
```

When I try to do this via batch script:

```
start powershell curl https://some-url.com -O target.csv
```

it doesn't save the file. I´ve tried it also with `>> target.csv` and I get the file with no content.

It should run on a Windows 2008 Server with PowerShell 1 and installed curl.exe

**Edit:**
My actual bat File:

```
start powershell -noexit curl https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSV966X52f-JvdpwnJbFGeHFlG7uR48069MtD4tvPRintmqH_O2JEclIg6knXkKUuO-dGEhS69LdM1P/pub?gid=556715578&single=true&output=csv -O target.csv
```

When I'm using `""` at the URL I´m getting the following Error:

```
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:151
+ ... tvPRintmqH_O2JEclIg6knXkKUuO-dGEhS69LdM1P/pub?gid=556715578&&single=t ...
+                                                                ~~
Das Token "&&" ist in dieser Version kein gültiges Anweisungstrennzeichen.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:164
+ ... JEclIg6knXkKUuO-dGEhS69LdM1P/pub?gid=556715578&&single=true&&output=c ...
+                                                                ~~
Das Token "&&" ist in dieser Version kein gültiges Anweisungstrennzeichen.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

Without the `""` the download starts but it downloads not the desired data:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Kleine Zeitung Paid Content</title><meta name="viewport" content=
                    "target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=2.5,initial-scale=1,wid
                    th...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet
                    Cache-Control: private, max-age=300
                    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
                    Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2019 12:36:20 GMT
                    Expires: Thu, 07 Mar 2019...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[X-Robots-Tag, noindex, nofollow, nosnippet], [Cache-Control, private, max-age=300],
                    [Content-Type, text/html; charset=utf-8], [Date, Thu, 07 Mar 2019 12:36:20 GMT]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {@{innerHTML=Google Sheets; innerText=Google Sheets; outerHTML=<A title="Learn more about Google
                    Sheets" href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/?usp=sheets_web" target=_blank>Google
                    Sheets</A>; outerText=Google Sheets; tagName=A; title=Learn more about Google Sheets;
                    href=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/?usp=sheets_web; target=_blank}, @{innerHTML=Missbrauch
                    melden; innerText=Missbrauch melden; outerHTML=<A href="https://docs.google.com/abuse?id=e/2PACX-1v
                    SV966X52f-JvdpwnJbFGeHFlG7uR48069MtD4tvPRintmqH_O2JEclIg6knXkKUuO-dGEhS69LdM1P">Missbrauch
                    melden</A>; outerText=Missbrauch melden; tagName=A; href=https://docs.google.com/abuse?id=e/2PACX-1
                    vSV966X52f-JvdpwnJbFGeHFlG7uR48069MtD4tvPRintmqH_O2JEclIg6knXkKUuO-dGEhS69LdM1P}}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 2179532
```

**Edit2**
We figured out that the `&` is the Problem, so I've tried many variations, `%26` `\&` `&amp;` `'&'` `"&"` but none of them worked properly.

When I'm starting it manually via PowerShell it's working, as a bat it isn't - mostly the same Error (Error 1).

So I need to find a way to use the `&` in a batch file.

**Edit3**

*Finally solved*

```
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSV966X52f-JvdpwnJbFGeHFlG7uR48069MtD4tvPRintmqH_O2JEclIg6knXkKUuO-dGEhS69LdM1P/pub?gid=556715578'&'single=true'&'output=csv"
```

As you see the Problem/Solution has been the double quotes and the single quotes
Thank You!

Comment: `start "" powershell -Command "curl https://some-url.com -O target.csv"`  maybe?

Comment: If you're using a batch script, why do you need to run curl from `powershell.exe`? it should be able to function directly from the batch file under `cmd.exe`!

Comment: Sorry, but it doesnt work. No target.csv was build.

Comment: Don't be sorry, instead, be a little less broad with your comment. Show us the exact command that you have used and properly explain what messages are output and any observations you may have made when doing so. That code and information should be added to your post, by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55042706/edit), it does not belong, _in an unformated state_, within the comment area. Please also note that when running from a batch file, a character commonly found in URL's, **`%`**, is a special character and must be doubled, **`%%`**!

Comment: Okay, you appear to have ampersands, **`&`**, in your URL. In a batch file ampersands are also poison characters. However, the method of alleviating that is not to double it. You would either enclose your URL in doublequotes, _(recommended)_, or escape those characters with the standard escape character, the caret, **`^`**. Try `curl "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSV966X52f-JvdpwnJbFGeHFlG7uR48069MtD4tvPRintmqH_O2JEclIg6knXkKUuO-dGEhS69LdM1P/pub?gid=556715578&single=true&output=csv" -O target.csv` first.

Comment: I´ve tried you suggestion. 
In the Powershell it works fine - as a batch file i get an Error, like the first Error in my Question.

Comment: As `curl` in PowerShell is just an alias for `Invoke-Webrequest` and recent windows 10 versions come with curl.exe preinstalled in 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\curl.exe' the queston is, which one do you want to use?

Comment: I need to use `curl.exe` because its running on a Windows Server 2008 with installed curl (powershell version1)

Comment: What happens if you put the option before the URL, `curl <options> URL`, i.e. `@curl -o target.csv "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSV966X52f-JvdpwnJbFGeHFlG7uR48069MtD4tvPRintmqH_O2JEclIg6knXkKUuO-dGEhS69LdM1P/pub?gid=556715578&single=true&output=csv"`? This seems to work on the Windows 10 PC, I've just tested it on.

Comment: It worked in the powershell. when I make a bat file I get the same Error again.

Comment: Create a batch file which contains only the one line I provided in my last comment. Please note however that I tested it in an OS which holds `curl.exe` within `%PATH%`, you may need to provide the full path to curl in your batch file, `@"C:\My Directory\Sub-Directory\curl.exe" -o target.csv "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSV966X52f-JvdpwnJbFGeHFlG7uR48069MtD4tvPRintmqH_O2JEclIg6knXkKUuO-dGEhS69LdM1P/pub?gid=556715578&single=true&output=csv"`.Then double click it, I've tested it and it produced the output as `target.csv` along side that one line batch file.

Comment: Thank You @Compo! I also got always a target.csv, either an empty one or it has the 'wrong' data. It was a problem with the `&`and finally we solved it:
`"http://....'&'....'&'....".`    **Thank You**

Comment: If you found the solution it would be better to post it as an answer rather than to include it in your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You @Compo!

I also got always a target.csv, either an empty one or it has the 'wrong' data.

It was a problem with the `&` and finally we solved it:

```
"http://....'&'....'&'...."
```

**Thank You**